# Why is jIndent breaking my C++ syntax?

Tags: c++, formatter

I've got a weird problem where jIndent seems to be stripping spaces between 'new' and type names, thus breaking the code.

For example,

```
Ball* b = new Ball[numBalls]; --->  Ball* b = newBall[numBalls];
```

Has anyone got any idea why? Could someone please export their working settings and post them here?

Thanks.

Comment: did you make the copy paste from any place? Sometimes due to char set this may happen

Comment: @prabhakaran - Thanks for the suggestion. I set everything to UTF-8 and started a new project, but unfortunately the same thing still happens. jIndent seems to have a bug of some sort though, as the output character encoding appears to revert to cp1252 (the system default), despite explicitly setting it to something else.

Answer (score 1):

No obvious reason from what you have told us as to why jindent should be misbehaving.

Standard first things to try/check:

- do you have the latest version of the product (which should have the most bugfixes)

  does the provider of the product have a public bug tracking system you can search
    for a similar problem (and assocaited fix)

  can you reproduce the error in a minimalist source code, which could be submitted
    to the provider as a bug report.

.PMCD.